# AccessDeniedException when accessing REST API that returns StreamingResponseBody in Spring Boot 3 and latest Spring Security?

Tags: mp3, access-denied, spring-boot-3, streamingresponsebody, spring-security-6

I have created this api for streaming an mp3 audio file as response.

```
@GetMapping (value = "/api/user/stream/{songId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> playSong(@PathVariable Long songId) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(projectPath + "\\assets\\audio\\DummySong" + ".mp3");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

        StreamingResponseBody songStream = out -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
                IOUtils.copy(in, out);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Streaming Thread Interrupted - {}", e.getMessage());
            }
            
        };

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_RANGES, "128")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
                    .contentLength(file.length())
                    .body(songStream);        
    }
```

**Spring Security Config**

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
                authorizeHttpRequests
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/signin", "/auth/signup", "/docs/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/artist/**").hasAnyRole("ARTIST", "ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        http.exceptionHandling((exceptionHandling) ->
            exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint((req, resp, e) -> {
                LOGGER.error("Error during auth: {}", e.getMessage());
                resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
            }));

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
```

Once I hit this api using Postman the response comes correctly and also the song plays as expected, but in the server terminal I am getting the following errors.

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
```

**And**
**as root cause**

```
2023-08-17T18:35:48.233+05:30 ERROR 10528 --- [0.0-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with pat
h [] threw exception [Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed.] with root cause.
```

Please help me figure out what is going wrong and how I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. A detailed solution is available in the post below.
[Spring Security 6 Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12758)

We have to create a bean of `RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository` in the app config.

```
@Bean
public RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository getRequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository() {
    return new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository();
}
```

Now, we have to set the context as follows in our `JwtTokenFilter` class.

```
class JwtTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    ...
    ...

    @Autowired
    private RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository repo;

    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) {
        ....
        ....
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        repo.setContext(context, req, res);
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy solution is to allow requests coming from ASYNC Dispatcher as follows:

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(
        (authorize) -> **authorize.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ASYNC).permitAll()**
                .requestMatchers("/auth/signin", "/auth/signup", "/docs/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/api/artist/**").hasAnyRole("ARTIST", "ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
```

this way request coming from ASYNC requests (basically the ones launched when processing the StreamingResponseBody) will not be affected by your application's security

Comment: Jose Luis - will not that also impact the other ASYNC requests besides StreamingResponseBody?

Comment: What other async request do you expect to have?